# What are the prerequisites for reading Generatingfunctionology?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question, self-learning, generating-functions

Which specific topics (e.g. calc 1, calc 2, linear algebra, etc.) do I need to study in order to be able to read and understand Wilf's [Generatingfunctionology](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)?

Comment: very basic, essentially calculus

Comment: How much calculus do I need to know? calc 1? calc 2? multivariable calc?

Comment: take a look at the book and you will see. As far I remember basically simple derivatives and integrals in the real line

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 5: Analytic and Asymptotic Methods
this will require complex analysis

Of course you can omit that chapter.  But in the Preface we find:

> To omit those parts of the subject, however, is like listening to a stereo recording of, say, Beethoven's Ninth Symphony, using only the left audio channel.

Amazon will show you a [sample](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568812795) of the book, including the Preface.  Why not read that to see whether to study the book.

Comment: the book *generatingfunctionology* is free of charge, you can download directly from the official web (already linked by the OP)